# Apply series of changes to multiple similar datasets in R

Tags: r

I have 20 csv files of data that are formatted exactly the same, about 40 columns of different numbers, but with different values in each column. I want to apply a series of changes to each data frame in order to extract specific information from every one of them.

Specifically I want to extract four columns from each data frame, find the maximum value of each column in each data frame and then add all of these maximum values together, so I get one final number for each data frame. Something like this:

```
str(data)    
Extract<-data[c(1,2,3,4)]
Max<-apply(Extract,2,max)
Add<-Max[1] + Max[2] + Max[3] + Max[4]
```

I have the code written above to do all these steps for every data frame individually, but is it possible to apply this code to all of them at once?

Comment: Why don't you just loop over the 20 csv files and repeat the procedure already tested for a single file?

Comment: Have you done any searching on google?

Comment: Yes I recognize I have to loop through each data file but I don't understand how to do it with all these separate commands.

Comment: @GR1818 Please consider accepting an answer from the ones below (check mark to the left of answers). It lets the community know the answer worked and that your issue is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all 20 filenames into a vector called `files`

```
Maxes <- numeric(length(files))
i <- 1

for (file in files) {

     data <- read.csv(file)
     str(data)    
     Extract<-data[c(1,2,3,4)]
     Max<-apply(Extract,2,max)
     Add<-Max[1] + Max[2] + Max[3] + Max[4]
     Maxes[i] <- Add
     i <- i+1

}
```

Though that `str(data)` will just cause a lot of stuff to print to the terminal 20 times.  I'm not sure the value of that, but it was in your question so I included.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your files into a common folder such as `/path/temp/`

```
csvs <- list.files("/path/temp")   # vector of csv
```

Use custom function for `colMax`

```
colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Using `foreach`, `dplyr`, and `readr`

```
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)

foreach(i=1:length(csvs), .combine="c") %do% { read_csv(csvs[i]) %>%
                                                select(1:4) %>% 
                                                colMax(.) %>% 
                                                sum(.)
                                             }  # returns a vector
```